# Format for hdr_sub pattern matching

Tags: haproxy, template, consul

I am trying to match the value of a header which has a space in it and cannot figure out what regex expressions haproxy likes. The header I'm after looks like this:

```
X-Request-ID:'Foo: Bar'
```

I would be Ok to match exactly this header or anything that starts with it.
However, I do NOT want to match 'Foo: Other'
My attempts so far:

```
acl badhdr hdr_sub(X-Request-ID) -i Foo: Bar
```

Matched anything that starts with Foo

```
acl badhdr hdr_sub(X-Request-ID) -i Foo:\sBar
```

didn't match 'Foo: Bar' at all...

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost inclined to think that the fact that HAProxy accepts this...

```
acl badhdr hdr_sub(X-Request-ID) -i Foo: Bar
```

...may be a bug, and " Bar" is being silently discarded.  I'd have to research further to be sure, but the correct way to express this would be a space escaped with a backslash...

```
acl badhdr hdr_sub(X-Request-ID) -i Foo:\ Bar
```

...or to enclose the expression in quotes...

```
acl badhdr hdr_sub(X-Request-ID) -i "Foo: Bar"
```

Note that `_sub` is not regex -- it's only substring matching.  You might want `hdr_beg` -- beginning substring.

For an anchored regex, including the beginning `'` (assuming that's part of the header, as it appears to be from the question, it also needs to be escaped), I believe the expression would be this:

```
acl badhdr hdr_reg(X-Request-ID) -i ^\'Foo:\ Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt), hdr_sub accepts substring matches as a parameter.

According to the documentation on HTTP header manipulation (same link), the substring regexes are a bit unconventional:

```
\t   for a tab
\r   for a carriage return (CR)
\n   for a new line (LF)
\    to mark a space and differentiate it from a delimiter
\#   to mark a sharp and differentiate it from a comment
\\   to use a backslash in a regex
\\\\ to use a backslash in the text (*2 for regex, *2 for haproxy)
\xXX to write the ASCII hex code XX as in the C language
```

Thus, this should work for you:

```
acl badhdr hdr_sub(X-Request-ID) -i Foo:\ Bar
```

Comment: In my case I was matching a url parameter trying to catch  userid=blahORDER BYblah    The solution turned out to be just    acl bot-path url_param -i -m sub ORDER%20BY